# looping checkbox, label and img together

Tags: php, html, checkbox, while-loop

My project works completely fine not until I inserted the image tag, that's where looping and the position of the checkbox, label and image gone wrong.

See this image below:

[This is what happened when I tried to insert the img tag together with the checkbox and label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikpyf.jpg)

Help me solve this problem, I wanted the photos to align by 3.

this is the generate source:

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="structure.css">
       </head>
       <body>


    <form action="another_sample.php" method="POST">

         <img class='img-foods' src='food_menu/25-07-17-1500971164.jpeg'><br><label><input type='checkbox' name='food[]' value ='100'>Asado</label><img class='img-foods' src='food_menu/25-07-17-1500971183.jpeg'><br><label><input type='checkbox' name='food[]' value ='100'>Broccoli</label><img class='img-foods' src='food_menu/25-07-17-1500971422.jpeg'><br><label><input type='checkbox' name='food[]' value ='100'>Stew</label><br><br><br><img class='img-foods' src='food_menu/25-07-17-1500971438.jpeg'><br><label><input type='checkbox' name='food[]' value ='100'>Teriyaki</label><img class='img-foods' src='food_menu/25-07-17-1500971452.jpeg'><br><label><input type='checkbox' name='food[]' value ='100'>Caldereta</label><img class='img-foods' src='food_menu/25-07-17-1500971463.png'><br><label><input type='checkbox' name='food[]' value ='100'>Kare-Kare</label><br><br><br><img class='img-foods' src='food_menu/25-07-17-1500971474.jpeg'><br><label><input type='checkbox' name='food[]' value ='100'>Lengua</label><img class='img-foods' src='food_menu/25-07-17-1500971496.jpeg'><br><label><input type='checkbox' name='food[]' value ='100'>Mongolian</label><img class='img-foods' src='food_menu/25-07-17-1500971508.jpeg'><br><label><input type='checkbox' name='food[]' value ='100'>Morcon Rolls</label><br><br><br><img class='img-foods' src='food_menu/25-07-17-1500971518.jpeg'><br><label><input type='checkbox' name='food[]' value ='100'>Roast Beef</label>        </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

this is the whole code that I created.

**HTML, PHP**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="structure.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action="another_sample.php" method="POST">
         <?php
            include "connection.php";
            $sql = "SELECT m.type, m.name, m.price, m.image, mt.name as 'type' FROM table_menu m LEFT JOIN table_menu_type mt ON m.type = mt.id WHERE m.type LIKE '%1%' ";
            $result = $con->query($sql);
            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                // output data of each row
                $x = 1;
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {  
                echo "<label><input type='checkbox' name='food[]' value ='". $row['price']."'>";
                echo  $row['name']."</label> <br>";
                echo "<img class='img-foods' src='food_menu/". $row['image'] ."'>";           
                $x++;
                  if($x > 3){
                       echo "<br>";
                        $x=1;
                        }                                                      
                 }
            } 
            else {
                echo "0 results";
            }
            $con->close(); 
            ?>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: I wanted the output to align by 3, but it doesn't go that way since the img tag ruining the code... I'm looking for someone who knows what is the problem. Been debugging this for good hours.

Answer (score 0):

You need to style your HTML using CSS. Also, you need to put the image inside the label. Generate this markup:

```
         <label><img class='img-foods' src='http://via.placeholder.com/100x100'><br />
         <input type='checkbox' name='food[]' value ='100'>Asado</label>

         <label><img class='img-foods' src='http://via.placeholder.com/100x100'><br />
         <input type='checkbox' name='food[]' value ='100'>Broccoli</label>

         <label><img class='img-foods' src='http://via.placeholder.com/100x100'><br />
         <input type='checkbox' name='food[]' value ='100'>Stew</label>
         <br />
```

Style it with this CSS:

```
label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

So your PHP should be like this:

```
echo "<label><img class='img-foods' src='food_menu/". $row['image'] ."'><br /><input type='checkbox' name='food[]' value ='". $row['price']."'>";
echo  $row['name']."</label>";
```

See how it should look here https://jsfiddle.net/uxmz9u4m/4/

Comment: another thing is, I'm using php that calls the image from the database.... can I use php on css? I'm new to this

Comment: Just paste your HTML that your loop generates and we'll get you sorted

Comment: My HTML and PHP is in one page, I posted it. See above.

Comment: I'm really just having problems in this part

Comment: $x = 1;
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {  
                echo "<label><input type='checkbox' name='food[]' value ='". $row['price']."'>";
                echo  $row['name']."</label> <br>";
                echo "<img class='img-foods' src='food_menu/". $row['image'] ."'>";           
                $x++;
                  if($x > 3){
                       echo "<br>";
                        $x=1;
                        }                                                      
                 }

Comment: Please can you visit your page, click view > source, and copy the relevant bit of GENERATED HTML? Not the PHP!

Comment: you mean at the F12 source of the browser?

Comment: yes please, just edit your question and paste it below the php script

Comment: there you go :o

Comment: what size are your images in pixels?

Comment: Ok, I have added a JS Fiddle here. https://jsfiddle.net/uxmz9u4m/ So you need 3 images in a row, with the checkbox next to them, or under them? I'll adjust markup, add CSS, and then figure out what to change in the PHP

Comment: under them :o whoah... Thanks a lot. Thank you <3

Comment: ah, i started too early. Look here for side by side https://jsfiddle.net/uxmz9u4m/2/

Comment: oh, whenever I tried to put it under by using <br> it goes back to the same problem :( Thanks for trying thou, Thank you :)

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH SIR :D <3